# MS Access popup form conditional on combobox value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working on a database to store a heap of animal behavioural observation data and am working on creating a form to input data (one of many forms). The main form feeds into a table called `"FocalSample"` and the subform feeds into a `"FocalData"` table. 
[This is the form at present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaXiR.png)
There will be multiple records in the subform to a single overarching sample, a sample is a 10 minute period and a single animals behaviour is documented over that 10 minutes, noting time in minutes and seconds to calculate duration of time spent in each behaviour.

I need popup forms to come up depending on what is selected in the `"Behaviour Type"` field of the subform, as the kind of data recorded for a `"feed"` observation compared to a `"social"` observation is very different. I have created separate tables for the different behaviour types of data and forms that are set as `"popup"` forms, but need help with the code to get it to do what I need! :P

I have been trying a variation of the following code that I found here (http://www.justskins.com/forums/pop-up-form-based-238440.html)

```
Private Sub Campaign_AfterUpdate()
Dim strFormName As String
Select Me.Campaign.Value
Case "In Honor", "In Memory"
strFormName = "HonorMemory"
Case "In-Kind"
strFormName = "InKind"
End Select
DoCmd.OpenForm strFormName, , , , , acDialog
End Sub
```

But I keep getting an error message after the first row.
[Here is the error and code screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcui3.png)

Similar to the other forum link I attached, I also need the popup form to draw a lot of info from the main form, but I'd just be happy to be able to get the popup forms working at the moment.

Sorry for so much detail - I am in a remote area of Africa and only have limited access to internet so am trying to give as much info up front!

[Example of popup form - you might be able to determine fields that will feed off the focalsample form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QHr4.png)
[Another example of a popup form - different behaviour type to the previous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J2YV.png)

**EDIT**
I have jigged the code now based off previous response but am not getting a different error.[This is the code with the error line highlighted -  I am not sure what table name to add if any](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zjVu.png)
[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s500k.png)

Answer (score 0):

The line `Select Me.Campaign.Value` should read `Select Case Me.Campaign.Value`.

Comment: Thankyou!! that's the line that kept throwing up the error! One issue fixed! Yay!

How do I need to edit the code to make it a different pop up form for each combo box value? any ideas? :D